# Link between tape drive library index and its serial number on linux

Tags: linux, tape, tapedrive

I need to map system devices to their index in tape library on linux.
How could I know by what index number in mtx command refers to a particular drive?
I can get mapping between drive serial numbers and system devices, through sg_inq or similar. But how to get tapechanger configuration about tape drive indexes?

UPDATE: Tape library I'm testing it on is MHVTL

Answer (score 1):

Not possible.

I've last looked at this in 2008, but there was no such universal method. Generally SCSI protocol (+descendants) for a tape library lacked at the time the possibility to ask a tape library "what is the serial number of your drive device in slot 5". At the time it could be queried only with a non-standard vendor specific methods, some had quirky ways to accomplish it.

Comment: But backup software such as NetBackup, TSM, Veeam do this. It should be possible somehow.

Comment: Both Netbackup and TSM have heuristics to detect a vendor. Please include the tape library brand/type in your question, if you have a specific device in mind.

Comment: I've updated question. For my tests I'm using mhvtl.